# How to change the value of a cell with Excel vba using a cell reference from a cell in another worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

We have two worksheets:

1. Reference
2. Operator

Suppose the cell d2 in the Reference sheet contains the value $a$25 .

How to change the value of the cell $a$25 in the Operator sheet using Excel VBA (referencing the address from d2 in the Reference sheet)?

What I have tried:

1. Capturing the reference in d2 with a variable:

```
    Dim NewRNG as Range
    NewRNG = Range(Range("d2").value).value
```

No luck here.

2. Finding the reference cell in Operator and using the found cell's address

```
    Sub Find_Cell()
    
    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim NewRNG as Range
    
    With Sheets("Operator").Range("A:A")
    
        Set RNG = .Find(What:=Sheets("Reference").Range("d2"), _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    End With
                    
    NewRNG = RNG.Address
    
    NewRNG.select
        
    End Sub
```

**in this case, i can't set rng.address to a variable

Comment: What have you tried and what is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: You need to at least try and work it out, and tell us a) what you've tried & b) why it doesn't. Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: Updated with some things I've tried. Thanks

Comment: Add a breakpoint to `NewRNG = RNG.Address` and see what `RNG.Address` is set to, or add a debug.print after the `End With` as `debug.print RNG.Address`. Is `.Address` a valid property of `Range`?